# WinBioEnrollCommit failes with error 0x80004005 (Unspecified Error)

Tags: c++, winapi, smartcard, biometrics, gemalto

I am following the example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401620(v=vs.85).aspx to enroll a fingerprint to a smart card.

I can capture the fingerprints, but during WinBioEnrollCommit I get the error "WinBioEnrollCommit failed" with the errorcode 0x80004005.

I have simply copied the example code and all the other examples run fine.

What am I missing here?

I have the strong feeling that i have to authenticate at the smart card to make these changes. If I use the software provided by the manufacturer (gemalto), I have to authenticate via challenge-reponse.

Edit:
When I try to enroll a finger that has already been enrolled, I get the proper error  WINBIO_E_DUPLICATE_TEMPLATE.